# Can I transfer Starbound Worlds from one character to another?

Tags: starbound

I'm playing with some friends, and I have our homeworld, but I want to play with a new character. Is there a way to keep said homeworld with my new character? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

All characters share the same universe. All you would have to do is copy down the coordinates of your home planet for one character, and fly to it with the other.

Hope this helps!